# What determines whether the Ridgeway is open?

Tags: borderlands

I've been traveling back to T-Bone Junction to finish some of the missions, and I find on my way to the Sunken Sea that some of the time, the Ridgeway is blocked halfway through so that you have to fight or run past a few dozen Crimson Lance warriors. However, the other half of the time the roadblock is gone, and I can just drive through the area instead.

Is there anything in particular that determines whether the road will be blocked or not?

Searching around, I've found several different theories:

- [The Wiki page for the Ridgeway](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/The_Ridgeway) says that it depends on your mission status:

> If Prison Break: Try Not to Get Shanked is active or has not yet been accepted, the blockade near the end of the road will be in place. If Athena is rescued, the blockade will be down and can be driven through. The blockade will only reappear should the currently active quest take place in the Sunken Sea or one of the several locations within.

However, I attempted this when my only active missions ("You. Will. Die" and "Super-Marcus Sweep") were on the other side of the level, and the roadblock was still up.

- [A poster on GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/942810-borderlands/54059186) thinks it's the opposite, that the roadblock is **down** once you've destroyed it only if you've got a mission in that direction.
- Several people, including [this post on the Gearbox forums](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=102885), seem to indicate that it's just random.
- [One person suggests](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:The_Ridgeway_Drive-thru_issue) that "if you kill the Lancers before you get to that area, the blockade appears, if you drive past them, it's clear". However, I was fairly certain that the roadblock had been up several of the times that I just drove past everything.

Is there any consensus (preferably with an official source)?

Comment: If it seems random, it may only be worth testing a few simple algorithm theories, like whether or not it's open if the map is generated on an even or odd second, a prime number second, a power-of-2 second or somesuch.